# Writing a query to select specific foreign key entries given a specific criteria

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

So I have a table that has a `FK` to a `UserId`, and a `FK` to a `ProductId`.

Each `UserId` can be listed multiple times if they have multiple products.

I need to query to get each `UserId` that has, for example, `ProductId 1`, but NOT `ProductId 2`.

How can I get started writing a query like this?

**Edit:**

But here is the part I'm having problems with; all users who have Product 1 should have Product 2, but some don't, so I need to get the users who have Product 1 and NOT Product 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select distinct userID from yourtable t
where t.ProductId=@ProductID1
and not exists(select UserID from yourtable 
                      where Userid=t.userID and ProductID=@ProductID2)
```

Answer (score 2):

-- Is this what you want?

```
SELECT 
    u.[UserID]
  , p.[ProductID]
FROM TableA a
    LEFT JOIN Users u ON
        u.[UserID] = a.[UserID]
    LEFT JOIN Products p ON
        p.[ProductID] = a.[ProductID]
WHERE a.ProductID = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

assuming you have a bridge table between `user` and `product`

if you want more then the id

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.name
FROM [user] AS u
INNER JOIN user_product AS up 
        ON u.user_id = up.user_id
INNER JOIN product as p 
        ON p.product_id = up.product_id
WHERE p.id = 1
```

or you can just query your bridge table

```
SELECT up.user_id
FROM user_product AS up
WHERE up.product_id = 1
```